# RegEx search for X if true then return emty string else return the whole string

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to find the correct RegEx for this problem:

I want to search a string for a value. If true, the result should be an emty string, otherwise the whole string.

Example

```
"We have apples, oranges, and peas"
```

Check for "apples" -> "

Check for "tomato" -> "We have apples, oranges, and peas"

I have to solve it using a standard RegEx statement. Since it is the only way I can modify the original string in the application.

Basically what I want to do is:

```
s="We have apples, oranges, and peas"

w="tomato"

IF instr(s,w)>0 then result="" else result=s
```

The problem is that the only way I can modify the string is by a regex syntax

I believe I have solved it by myself. Have no clue why it works :)

```
 (?(?=.*apples)|.*)|.*
```

returns nothing as I want

```
 (?(?=.*banana)|.*)|.*
```

returns We have apples, oranges, and peas

The following regex also works

```
 ^((?!apples).)*$
```

Comment: Which tool/language?

Comment: How is this a duplicate?

Comment: The string `We have apples, oranges, and please` does not contain `tomato`, and OP wants to get it. Thus, the question is a dupe.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, and he wants to match an empty string if there is a `tomato`, not return `null`/no match or whatever the default behavior in the language is. Thus the question is different.

Comment: I disagree. And don't worry: SO is a democratic site: if others agree it is so different, then the question will be reopened.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, if others cared to check the question out... you can be pretty sure max 1-2 people looked at the question after you closed it, of them probably noone had enough reputation to cast reopen votes.